# How to display image path dynamically?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following code

```
<figure>
<?php if ($data[$i]->thumbnail) { ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $img ?>" width="465" height="300" alt="news-report-juli19" title="" />
<?php } ?>
</figure>
```

I want to display images from mysql database dynamically,
the image_field_name=thumbnail.
I have 10 records in db  and all have different images.

Comment: please read this, it explains it very well: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news, where news stands for image

Comment: hey @Vickel,i am display content and text very well but problem is with image,its img-src doesn't  exist and unable to locate image form media folder

Comment: you stored an image as blob or the image path?

Comment: please put your file all path

Answer (score 0):

use query variale with db colmn where images are present

use this in source img src

```
echo $query_variable['db_coln_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to given the image path as well when you want to display.

```
<?php if ($data[$i]->thumbnail) { ?>
  <img src="<?php echo base_url('path_of_img/$img'); ?>" width="465" height="300" alt="news-report-juli19" title="" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Codeigniter framework, please try this.
In controller

```
$data['images'] = $this->model->get_images();
$this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```

In model you should make get_images() method that get image urls.

In view

```
<?php
    foreach ($images as $value) {
       echo '<img src="'.$value['thumbnail'].'" width="465" 
               height="300" alt="news-report-juli19" title="" />';
    }
?>
```

Good luck.